# Integrating indicator function

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am trying to integrate $f(t,\tau)=I(t \leq \tau)$ with respect to $\tau$ where $\tau$ is random variable that follows some distribution$(eg; Uniform[1,5])$ and $t > 0$. Any help would be appreciated? I am reading some paper and they don't show all the steps.

Comment: I am not sure but what would be the result in this case?

Comment: Basically, I want to get the marginal function f(t) by integrating out tau.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. So basically the integral equals 1 - CDF.

Comment: I am afraid you mostly missed the point in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To compute$$\int_1^5 \mathbb I_{t\le \tau}\,\text{d}\tau/4$$one need break the domain of integration $(1,5)$ into the part where the indicator is zero, which is when $\tau<t$, namely
$$(1,5)\cap(-\infty,t)=\begin{cases}\varnothing &\text{when }t<1\\(1,\min\{5,t\}) &\text{when }t>1\end{cases}$$
and the part where the indicator is one, namely
$$(1,5)\cap(t,\infty)=\begin{cases}\varnothing &\text{when }t>5\\(\max\{1,t\},5) &\text{when }t<5\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$\int_1^5 \mathbb I_{t\le \tau}\,\text{d}\tau=\begin{cases}
\int_1^5\,\text{d}\tau &\text{when }t<1\\
\int_t^5 \,\text{d}\tau&\text{when }1<t<5\\
0 &\text{when }t>5\end{cases}$$
The extension to a non-uniform prior on $\tau$ is immediate.